# DB Plugin is not registered in Play 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, anorm

I just started working with play, and I modified the way I'm doing a SQL read and I'm now getting the following error:

```
[Exception: DB plugin is not registered.]
```

The code I have for this class is:

```
package models

import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import anorm._

case class Housing(id: Long, rent: String, address: String, street0: String, street1: String, neighbourhood: String)

object Housing {

  def all(): List[Housing] = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
    SQL("select * from housing")().map { row =>
      Housing(row[Long]("id"), row[String]("rent"), row[String]("address"), row[String]("street0"),
        row[String]("street1"), row[String]("neighbourhood"))
    }.toList
  }

  def create(rent: String, address: String, street0: String, street1: String, neighbourhood: String) {}

  def delete(id: Long) {}

}
```

I'm not sure this is even the best way to do this, but using the ~ chain seemed like I'd just end up duplicating a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out that somehow in the application.conf the line:

```
dbplugin=disabled
```

had arisen.  Not sure, I know I didn't put it in there, but commenting it out and fixing the remaining config errors in the JDBC Url fixed the problem!

Comment: I had the same problem. And i forgot to uncomment this one db.default.driver.

Comment: I do not have this line at all

Comment: it happened with me as well when running tests through IntelljJ. I have this line disable since I am using HikariCP instead of BoneCP (which is default for play 2.2). My tests run fine using play command (```play test```) but for some reason intelliJ doesn't load hikariCP and errors out with above mentioned error

Answer (score 13):

Just make sure you provide the database configuration. For example, if you are using Play Framework's tutorial, uncomment this section.

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
# db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
# db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""**
```

For more information, see [Play Framework Database Configuration](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaDatabase)

Comment: very useful. was stepping through the tutorial and forgot this!

Comment: Relevant answer as per the version 2.2