# Using a database with the Play framework

Tags: database, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've been following this tutorial to get accustomed to the Play framework:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaTodoList

When reaching the "Persist the tasks in a database" segment, it is unclear to me whether I have to do anything to start up the database or if this is done automatically for me. I am currently receiving this error:

[Exception: DB plugin is not registered.]

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863095/db-plugin-is-not-registered-in-play-2-0)?

Comment: Yes, everywhere Google sent my I only came across that question. I couldn't find anything wrong with my application.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of database you use.

H2 database (the one used in Play! tutorial) can be used as [an in-memory database or as a disk based database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#feature_list). Play will handle all for you if you go for this database. You don't have to run a specific service to have the persistent database.

But you will have to describe in your `application.conf` which driver to use and which url to access :

> db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
>
> db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"

As you probably don't have the right driver in your classpath, you would have to include this driver lib. As explained in [Play2 documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/SBTDependencies), you can manage this in `project/Build.scala`. For [h2 driver lib](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html) the dependency will be :

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.167"
)
```

After having changed your dependencies, you will need to reload the application build file and update the dependencies :

```
//in sbt
reload
update
```

How to link your play application with a database is explained [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaDatabase)

If you want to use an other database (Mysql, Postgresql...) you will have to run the database service yourself and repeat the steps described here.

Comment: Upvoted for knowledge, however this still does not solve the issue. I've modified Build.scala and reloaded and update the whole project, yet the error persists. FWIW: After adding the 1.sql script file and refreshing the page I do NOT receive the Apply script page.

Comment: You should re-start from scratch the tutorial, the problem is in database plugin registration. You should have something wrong with your application.conf. Check that app "dbplugin = disabled" is not present and that you have a db.default conf in the file

Comment: The h2 driver is bundled with play 2, so it's not necessary to include the dependency. See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaDatabase