# Play 2.3.x: Multiproject, disable BoneCP

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, playframework-2.3, specs2

I've got a `Play` project with some subprojects. One of the subproject needs `JDBC`, so `BoneCP` (it accessed `MySQL` DB).

On the other hand, the root project doesn't need `JDBC` at all.

My problem is:
`JDBC` is declared in the `build.sbt` of the subproject. When I run all the tests, and in this case the root project tests, `BoneCP` is initialized, even if just needed in the subproject. It brings me some problems during testing:

```
Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]  (Configuration.scala:94)
```

Can I specify to `Play` to only use `JDBC` with the subproject ? Or can I disable `JDBC` or `BoneCP` in the root project ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Can you comment on your tests are they just unit tests or also integration tests ? Do some of them need BoneCP

Comment: Yep, some of them are Unit -> doesn't need BoneCP nor JDBC at all.
Some others are integration and need JDBC. 

Unit are in the root project, Integration (with JDBC) are in subproject.
Useful links for me:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects
https://github.com/josh-padnick/play-multiproject-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally get it !

`val withoutPlugins = Seq(classOf[ReactiveMongoPlugin].getName)`
Worked like a charm for disabling ReactiveMongo Plugin.

And for the main problem:
`additionalConfiguration = Map("dbplugin" -> "disabled", "evolutionplugin" -> "disabled")`

No `JDBC` at all during tests. Thank you a lot Barry !

Answer (score 0):

For the Unit tests I would say create a testing utility object that provides a common [FakeApplication](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/test/FakeApplication.html). Then you can re-use this FakeApp in your unit tests. One of the constructor arguments to FakeApplication is withoutPlugins which you can utilize to turn off plugins during unit testing.

For example in a current Play app we utilize ReactiveMongo but don't want this in unit testing.

```
object MockMyApp extends OurBaseSpec {
 val withoutPlugins = Seq(classOf[ReactiveMongoPlugin].getName)
 val appWithoutIntegrations = FakeApplication(withoutPlugins = withoutPlugins)
}
```

We then reference this MockMyApp.appWithoutIntegrations when creating new apps for unit testing. You can also specify additional configuration amongst other options when creating your FakeApp.

From a few links I think you might be looking for additional configuration  to set when you create your FakeApp :

```
    dbplugin=disabled
```

[Answer where above configuration was reason dbplugin wasn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863095/db-plugin-is-not-registered-in-play-2-0)

[Instructions for configuring alternate connection pool look at step#2](https://github.com/edulify/play-hikaricp.edulify.com)

```
   val disabledDbConfig = Map("dbplugin"->"disabled")
   val appWithoutIntegrations = FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = disabledDbConfig)
```

Comment: Hi, it seems to work for ReactiveMongo plugin. But for dbplugin, I got that: `there should be a database plugin registered at this point but looks like it's not available, so evolution won't work. Please make sure you register a db plugin properly`